# Sql Server With Scope

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I was wondering if there was any way to make the scope of a with statement more than just for the first statement after the with, for example

```
WITH cr AS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @rq ORDER BY h, f)
SELECT * FROM cr
DELETE cr FROM @rq
```

by the time the line `DELETE cr FROM @rq` is reached SQL SERVER no longer remembers what `cr` is and gives the error `Invalid object name 'cr'.`, I have tried adding begin and end blocks so it looked like

```
WITH cr AS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @rq ORDER BY h, f)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM cr
    DELETE cr FROM @rq
END
```

but that is invalid and gives the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.`

Can the scope of a with statement be expanded or was it always created to be used instantly and then no longer be accessible?

**NOTE:**

```
WITH cr AS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @rq ORDER BY h, f)
DELETE cr FROM @rq
```

works as does

```
WITH cr AS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @rq ORDER BY h, f)
SELECT * FROM cr
```

so both statements are allowed when the with statement is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you'd need to store the results of the CTE query in a table variable or temp table. There is an [open Microsoft Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/343067/module-level-table-expressions) requesting such functionality if you'd like to vote it up.

Comment: I have a user defined table type of the same type as @rq called rq, if i try declare @cr rq insert into @cr SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @rq ORDER BY h, f) and then try the DELETE @cr FROM @rq it doesnt delete the record can you suggest how to create a structure that will work in a similar way to the with structure?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you can combine the delete + select into a single expression you can use with your CTE by specifying an `OUTPUT`;

```
DECLARE @rq TABLE (h INT, f INT) INSERT @rq VALUES (5,0),(6,0),(7,0)

;WITH cr AS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @rq ORDER BY h, f)
DELETE cr
   OUTPUT DELETED.*
FROM @rq    

>>h f
>>5 0
```

Comment: that example was just to demonstrate what i meant in actual fact what i need cr for is a lot more than a select and delete i just wanted to know if i could specify a scope

Comment: Then no, you would replace the cte with a temp table / table variable